# Echo a string inside of an echo statement?

Tags: php, echo, return-value

This is probably a very simple one to be answered...

I have a piece of code which I need to pull a certain piece of information.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('XXXX')->toHTML();?>
```

For this to work I need the XXXX part to pull the result of the following query:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('warranty') ?>
```

So the output from the above query will then be the information needed to go in to XXXX.

This markup is completely wrong below but should demonstrate the idea I am trying to achieve:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('warranty') ?>')->toHTML();?>
```

Comment: Why couldn't you just do `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('warranty'))->toHTML();` ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the "<?php echo" and "?>" portions? The value that you're printing out is actually what you want substituted there, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a redundant PHP opening <?php inside the code. You are already in PHP context so you can do that call directly.

```
<?php  echo
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('warranty'))->toHTML();?>
```

However, this is quite complicated and difficult to debug. I would split it in several lines and use variables... remember that you can do it in that context, you are not bound to do everything in one line only :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe as simple as:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('warranty'))->toHTML();?>
```

If not then I would very much like to know what kind of var (array, int, string, double etc) the setBlockId function needs and what $_product->getAttributeText returns.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('warranty'))->toHTML();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
 echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('cms/block')
          ->setBlockId($_product->getAttributeText('warranty'))
          ->toHTML();
?>
```